# toJson instance single value

Tags: haskell, aeson

I am able to json-encode my data

```
import Data.Aeson                       (ToJSON, toJSON, (.=), object)
import qualified Data.Text      as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as L

data ServiceResponse = ReadServiceResponse  L.Text
                     | GenericServiceError  Int L.Text

instance ToJSON ServiceResponse where
    toJSON (ReadServiceResponse text)      = object ["text" .= text]
    toJSON (GenericServiceError code text) =
        object ["code" .= code, "message" .= text]
```

For data having only one "scalar" value (e.g. String, Int, L.Text, ...) I would like to get a scalar representation instead of an object. For example the `ReadServiceResponse` should be encoded into a json string instead of an object like

```
{
    text: "hi I'm some text."
}
```

I tried

```
instance ToJSON ServiceResponse where
    toJSON (ReadServiceResponse text) = text
```

which does not compile

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘aeson-1.3.1.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value’ with actual type ‘L.Text’
```

Should I transform `text` into a `Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value` (How can i do that)? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `toJSON` must return a value of type `Value`, you can't return `text` by itself; it has to be wrapped with the `String` data constructor.

```
toJSON (ReadServiceResponse text) = String text
```

Note that since `String :: T.Text -> Value`, this requires you to use the strict implementation of `Text` in the definition of `ReadServiceResopnse`:

```
data ServiceResponse = ReadServiceResponse  T.Text -- not L.Text
                     | GenericServiceError  Int L.Text
```

or doing a conversion in `toJSON`:

```
toJSON (ReadServiceResponse text) = String . T.pack . L.unpack $ text
```

Comment: I need some more help here: I get an error `Data constructor not in scope: String :: T.Text -> aeson-1.3.1.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value` It recommends me to add `String` to the import of `Data.Aeson` which does not work

Comment: If you are doing explicit imports, you need something like `import Data.Aeson (ToJSON, toJSON, (.=), object, Value(String))`; the data constructor `String` isn't imported "directly" from `Data.Aeson`. This allows a module to export a type without exposing its constructors; it only works because Aeson explicitly exports `Value(..)`, rather than just `Value`.

Comment: Aah thank you very much for explaining me how to import data constructors explicitly. Now it works, very cool!!

Comment: I refactored it a bit so that I use the following data `ReadServiceResponse String`. This avoids the pack/unpack into lazy text and looks more clean. `toJSON (ReadServiceResponse text) = String . T.pack $ text`.